# Installer packages for VS projects

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup

Can you recommend free/opensource installer packages for VS projects?

The setup project in VS2010 does not allow multiple components. Our deployments consist of multiple projects (web app, windows services, desktop apps, etc.).

I had experience with WIX but it requires configuring XML files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

More importantly, MSI setup projects are gone from newer versions of Visual Studio. You'll need to move on anyway.

Check here:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm

but I don't believe you'll find anything like that. WiX meets your requirements, and 1) There are UI additions you can use if you don't like Xml (such as Wixedit, WixAware) and 2) there is a huge number of WiX samples on the web, and most dev work is copy paste of Xml sections, not typing it all in yourself.

Comment: This looks like a good list. We'll check each of it and will give feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of free installation systems - Do you need any  open-source (free) one or something which works with Visual Studio?

I can recommend you to use NSIS [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) or Inno Setup [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php). 
These two systems are easy to learn but really powerful, both are script based and very popular. There are many examples, tutorials and huge community around (also here on SO) them.

They can be integrated directly into Visual Studio with **Visual & Installer** addin ([Visual & Installer website](http://visual-installer.com/)) (sorry for little self promo).

Here are few features:

- New project types: NSISProject  and InnoSetupProject
- Full integration into Visual Studio IDE
- Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2013 support
- Build installers directly with other project types
- NSISProject and InnoSetupProject properties
- Syntax highlighting (coloring)
- IntelliSense Complete Word support
- IntelliSense Parameter Info
- IntelliSense Quick Info
- Navigation Bars support
- Complete linkage to the solution build process
- Quick jump from Error List window
- Go To support
- Hints and tips for writing scripts*
- Code optimizations*
- Opening script files (Go To file)
- IntelliSense Code Snippets support
- Creating custom Code Snippets
- Plug-ins recognition*
- Full version control system support
- Dynamic help system
- Cross-version compatibility for all Visual Studio versions
- Convert VS Setup projects (.vdproj) into NSIS or Inno Setup!

I think currently it is the best Visual Studio solution for creating installers :)

Comment: We'll check it out and will send feedback, thanks! The removal of setup projects in VS is a very bad news to us.